# Incorrect order of M/D in datetimes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a date column in my csv file

This is my Date column data

```
14/3/18    
28/3/18  
9/4/2018
```

How to make the year all become 2018 ?

I have tried this

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
print (df['DateTime'])
```

but it return

```
1     2018-03-14
2     2018-03-28
3     2018-09-04
```

The Last column 09 become month but it supposed 04 is month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parameter `dayfirst=True`:

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
print (df)
       Date   DateTime
0   14/3/18 2018-03-14
1   28/3/18 2018-03-28
2  9/4/2018 2018-04-09
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.dt.strftime`:

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime']).dt.strftime("%Y-%d-%m")
```

Output:

```
0    2018-14-03
1    2018-28-03
2    2018-04-09
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Comment: OP need something else `The Last column 09 become month but it supposed 04 is month.`

Comment: I think op need datetimes, not strings